Understanding the following definition of a set monotone in another set
I have the following definition:
A set $A \subset H$ is monotone in $H$ if $\forall x \in A, \forall \epsilon \geq 0: x + \epsilon \in H \Rightarrow x + \epsilon \in A$.
Strictly monotone if $x+\epsilon \in \text{int}(H) \Rightarrow x + \epsilon \in \text{int}(A)$.
I find this a bit of an unintuitive definition. Are there any other definitions to this one? From what I understand, if $x$ is in $A$ and you can find a perturbation that is also in $H$, then this is in $A$.
But then, for example, given the interval of real numbers $H=[0,1]$, the only monotone set would be $[0,1]$? If I take an interval smaller than $[0,1]$, I will always find a number ($\neq 0 \text{ or } 1$) that if I perturb it with some $\epsilon\geq0$, it will be in $H$, therefore it is in $A$ and therefore $A=H$
Would a fitting example be one where we have a set of intervals $H$ such that the intersection of the intervals is not $H$. For example, $H = \{ [0,1] , [2,3], [4,5]\}$. A monotone set would then for example be $A=[2,3]$, and there can only be $2^3$ unique monotone sets?

If I am not mistaken, the definition you wrote means that $A$ is montone in $H$, if $(a,\infty)\cap H\subseteq A$ for all $a\in A$. Strictly monotone seems to say that an interior point of $H$ in the ray $(a,\infty)$, is also an interior point in $A$.
For $H=[0,1]$, any nonempty monotone set would be of the form $[a,1]$ or $(a,1]$. If $H=\{ [0,1], [2,3], [4,5] \}$, then $A=[2,3]\in H$ but not $A\subset H$. So it wouldn't make sense then. However, $H=[0,1] \cup [2,3] \cup [4,5]$ would have monotone sets of the form $H\cap (a,\infty)$ or $H\cap [a,\infty)$. In particular, there are uncountably many monotone subsets of $H$.

Ah yes of course, I was considering $x+\epsilon$ as well as $x-\epsilon$ oops. And thanks for the clarification on the use of element of and subset of, I mixed that up as well,
